# VECM representing an I(0) system?

Tags: vector-autoregression, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

I am referring to [Johansen (1991)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2938278) where he considers a $p$-dimensional autoregressive process of order $k$

$$ X_t = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \Pi_i X_{t-i} \ + \ \epsilon_t \tag{1}\label{1} $$

written in vector error correction form

$$ \Delta X_t = \Pi X_{t-1} \ + \ \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \Gamma_i \Delta X_{t-i} \ + \ \epsilon_t \tag{2}\label{2} $$

where $\Pi = \sum_{i=1}^k \Pi_i \ - \ I$ and $\Gamma_i = - \sum_{j=i+1}^k \Pi_j$.

He states without reference or proof that if the $\ p\times p \ $ matrix $\Pi$ has full rank then $X_t$ is a stationary process.

Can someone provide me with a reference or is able to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I will provide a reference and a quick intuition. In Lutkepohls "New introduction to multiple time series Analysis" (2005, p.248) he explains that full rank of $\Pi$ in equation (2) actually implies that $X$ is stationary. The rank of a matrix is directly related to its invertibility, full rank matrices are invertible and matrices of lower rank are singular. This is obvious if you think of the determinant as the product of the diagonal elements of the reduced matrix, when it is not full rank at least one element in this product is zero making the determinant zero. The invertibility of $\Pi$ has to do with the *stability* of $\Pi$, which in turn implies stationarity.

Comment: Thanks for providing this reference with your accompanying intuition. The explanation of why non-stationarity implies the singularity of $\Pi$ is found on the preceding page you're referring to (p.247). If the VAR determinantal polynomial has a unit root, an immediate consequence is that $det(\Pi)=0$. On the contrary, if $X$ is stationary the polynomial has no unit root and $det(\Pi) \neq 0$, showing that stationarity is equivalent to $\Pi$ having full rank.